# Can I compile SOX with AAC encoding support?

Tags: mp3, audio-recording, aac, sox

I'm using SOX to record raw PCM audio and encode it:

```
/usr/bin/rec --buffer 2000000 -c 1 -r 44100 -b 32 test.mp3
```

I'd like to use an AAC encoder instead of mp3, but SOX doesn't recognize aac. Is it possible to compile SOX with AAC encoding support?